# How can I get imgur.com album images using ajax request

Tags: ajax, imgur

I used this code :

```
    (function($){
    var albumID = 'NNbeO';
    var albumAPI = "https://api.imgur.com/3/album/" + albumID + "/images";

    $.ajax({
        url: albumAPI,
        headers:{
            'Authorization':'xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { 

            alert(data.data[0].link);

        },
        error: function() { console.log("ERRORZ"); }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But I got this error :

```
 {
      "data": {
        "error": "Malformed auth header",
        "request": "\/3\/album\/NNbeO\/images",
        "method": "GET"
      },
      "success": false,
      "status": 403
    }
```

Comment: No Delboud. Not found anything.

Comment: have you checked this answer, [Getting a 403..](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17391529/4381432)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my solution. It works fine now. Below is my working code. It's problem was, I've not added `Client-ID` text with **Authorization headers**.:

```
(function($){
var albumID = 'NNbeO';
var albumAPI = "https://api.imgur.com/3/album/" + albumID + "/images";

  $.ajax({
      url: albumAPI,
      headers:{
          'Authorization':'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      },
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) { 

          alert(data.data[0].link);

      },
      error: function() { console.log("ERRORZ"); }
  });

})(jQuery);
```